# Normalisation from 1NF to 3NF

Tags: database, database-normalization

If I have the following table which is currently in 1NF:

[image]

I am required to decompose this table into 3NF.

I would then have (correct me if I am wrong):

```
Customer(Customer ID-PK, Customer Name)
Branch(Branch ID-PK, Branch Name, BSB)
Account(Account Type-PK, Account Name)
```

What would I have for Account Details? I'm thinking something like:

```
Account Details (Account Number, Customer ID, Branch ID, Account Type, Account Balance)
```

I'm stuck on what to make the primary key of this main table as there are multiple customers on a single account number.

Would I be needing to use a composite primary key with Account Number and Branch ID?

What other/better options do I have here?

Comment: Why don't you merge Account and AccountDetails tables together?

Comment: You need to place most of your 'Account Details' into the 'Account' table — but you need a table to associate customer IDs with Account Numbers.  Note that The Hulk's account number is the same as that of Iron Man and Loki, but the branch numbers are different.  Thus, you need to reconsider your primary key on 'Account merged with Account Details'.

Comment: Hi. So what does your textbook say about doing this & what can you do & where are you stuck? What are your FDs? This post doesn't reflect any evidence of you following given steps to solve this. So an answer is essentially repeating your textbook & doing your homework. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the organization being modelled is a bank.

Given the sample data, it appears that the Branch ID, Branch Name and BSB are all associated with a specific branch, and each of the columns is a candidate key (could be 'the' primary key).

One of the 3NF tables should be:

```
Branch:  Branch ID, Branch Name, BSB — Branch ID nominated as PK
```

Only two bits of data are recorded for each customer: the customer name and their customer ID.  Since names can repeat, we'll assume the the customer ID is the candidate key.

One of the 3NF tables should be:

```
Customer: Customer ID, Customer Name — Customer ID nominated as PK
```

Given that the first two data rows and the last all identify a/c 9047 1234 but the account type information is different, the a/c number is not unique across all branches in the bank.  Based on the data shown, the combination of account number and Branch ID should be unique (and hence the PK).  However, a given account can be shared by more than one customer – witness the first two rows of data.

Consequently, one of the 3NF tables should be:

```
Account: Account Number, Branch ID, Account Type, Account Balance, Account Type, Account Name
— PK(Account Number, Branch ID)
```

And another should track the customer(s) associated with a given account number.  Again, the table shown is 'all key', with the `Account Number` and `Branch ID` forming one foreign key and the `Customer ID` being another.

```
Account_Customers: Customer ID, Account Number, Branch ID
```

So, I think you need 4 tables.  The primary key columns are marked with an asterisk.

- Branch:  Branch ID*, Branch Name, BSB
- Customer: Customer ID*, Customer Name
- Account: Account Number*, Branch ID*, Account Type, Account Balance, Account Type, Account Name
- Account_Customers: Customer ID*, Account Number*, Branch ID*

Answer (score 0):

You can create structure as follows,

```
Customer(Customer ID-PK, Customer Name)
Branch(Branch ID-PK, Branch Name, BSB)
Account(Account ID-PK, Account Number, Account Name, Branch ID, Account Type, Account Balance)
Account_Customer ( Account_Customer_id-PK, Account id, Customer ID)
```

You have to keep account related information at one place i.e. in account table itself.
Also for Account_Customer you can add active flags or from & to dates to keep more Customer & account related

Comment: Note that account number 9047 1234 occurs in two branches, with different account types, etc.  Thus account number plus branch ID (or perhaps BSB) is needed in the PK of `Account` — and you have to worry about the PK in your Account/Customer table too.

Comment: Well I have doubt that Account Number is repeated across different branches as I can see there are 2 account types for same account number 9047 1234.

I think it absolutely depends on business logic, which is not explained here.

Comment: Are we in agreement that the first two data lines and the last have the same account number, but different branch information, different customer information, and different account type and balance information? If not, we have major problems. Assuming we agree on that, then my interpretation is that an account number is not unique within the 'bank' (organization whose data is being modelled) — but, on the basis of the data shown, the combination of 'branch ID' and 'account number' is unique across the bank.  There might be other criteria for the unique key for the account; this one is simple.

Comment: From my understanding here, AccountNumber is not enough to uniquely identify the account. I'd have to combine it with BSB or BranchID, but that still leaves the problem of 1 account having multiple holders (customers). Would a composite PK with AccountNumber, BranchID, CustomerID be okay?

Comment: I think instead of composite PK, you should use surrogate key for account & account customer linking so that you can distinguish each account record on basis of account number & Branch ID

Comment: I have not yet been taught surrogate keys in my course, so I would not be expected to use it.

Comment: You can use sequence / another key for different combinations for the same.

Comment: Account Number cannot be primary key as it is repeated for combinations of  (Customer / Branch / Account type)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, one account has many customers. Do you also have other criteria like one customer can have many accounts ? 
If this is the case, then you have to design with many-to-many relationship.
Something like

```
Customer(PK, CustomerName)
Account(PK,AccountId,...)
AccountMapping(PK,(Account.PK/Customer.PK) AS FOR,(Account.PK/Customer.PK) AS TO)
```

Comment: The table is all that I’m given and I am asked to make it into 3NF. We are expected to use what is given along with common sense. I am allowed to make assumptions as long as I state them clearly.